# Issue while converting .ui to .py on PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

while converting **.ui to .py** using cmd command **pyuic5 -x file.ui -o file.py** an error occurs stating there is no pyuic batch file in internal and external

> PS-couldn't find pyuic.exe anywhere in the **scripts** folder

I have installed the pyqt5 using the wheel package

Comment: Find the location of the pyuicx.exe file and place it in the environment variables.

Comment: there was no pyuic5.exe file nowhere in the system so instead i used pyuic5.bat utility and it worked after reinstalling same version of both PyQt and python